# Why is the C# compiler claiming 'use of an unassigned variable' prior to 'yield return' and dynamic?

Tags: dynamic, c#-4.0, yield-keyword, out-parameters

The compiler complains that `resultingThing` in the code below is being used before being assigned to.

```
private IEnumerable<IThing> FindThings(dynamic spec)
{
    if (spec == null)
        yield break;

    IThing resultingThing;
    if (spec.Something > 0 && dictionary.TryGetValue(spec.Something, out resultingThing))
        yield return resultingThing;
    else
        // ...
}
```

Why does it claim this?

I have tried a different version of the method in which there are no **yield** usages (e.g. just `return IEnumerable<IThing>`) but with the **dynamic** parameter, and I have tried a version of the method in which **dynamic** is not passed in (i.e. what we've done in prior versions of C#). These compile.

Comment: Are you using `resultingThing` in the `else` case?

Comment: No not using `resultingThing` in the `else`. Also, initializing it to `null` gets rid of the compiler error as expected.

Comment: Not really ideal, but try initializing `resultingThing` using the `default` keyword, i.e. `default(IThing)`. For reference types, this should be `null`; for value types, it should be the equivalent of a default-constructed type.

Comment: I have reduced the error case, the iterator block has no influence, though the use of dynamic is relevant, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appears to be a compiler bug (or limitation, if you prefer).

I reduced the minimal failing case to:

```
static private IThing FindThings(dynamic spec)
{
    IThing resultingThing;
    if ((null!=spec) && dictionary.TryGetValue(spec, out resultingThing))
        return resultingThing;
return null;
}
```

Which gives the same compiler diagnostic, without involving member lookup on dynamics, nor iterator blocks.

For reference the mono compiler does *not* trip over that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class X
{
    public interface IThing { }

    private static readonly IDictionary<string, IThing> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, IThing>();

    static private IThing FindThings(dynamic spec)
    {
        IThing resultingThing;
        if ((null!=spec) && dictionary.TryGetValue(spec, out resultingThing))
            return resultingThing;
        return null;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] s)
    {

    }
}
```

Compiling that:

```
dmcs -v -warnaserror -warn:4 t.cs
```

No warnings

Comment: You didn't say whether your version was tested with the Microsoft C# compiler. So I tried it, and it does, in fact, produce the error given in the question title.

Comment: Yes, it was the Microsoft compiler. It looks like it is indeed a bug.